# Turing machine - definition of program - naive question

Tags: turing-machines

In the paradigm of Turing machines what is considered a program?
Can't find a definition anywhere.
Is it a member of L(M)?

Comment: Is L(M) a (an interpreted) programming language?

Answer (score 1):

The Turing machine itself is the program.

You can see this in universal Turing machines. A universal Turing machine accepts a description $\langle M \rangle$ of a Turing machine $M$ and an input $x$, and runs $M$ on $x$. Thus $M$ (or rather, $\langle M \rangle$) is the *code* or *program*, and $x$ is the *input* or *data*.

Comment: I ask because I'm new to computer science. So then the Euler number of a Turing machine is called the program, right?

Comment: I have never heard of an "Euler number" in this context. It's a non-standard concept.

Comment: There is no "program" in Turing machines. The Turing machine itself is the program. You can say that the Turing machine is analogous to a program, perhaps, but programs usually refer to textual descriptions of languages.